# I want to append the current path after the language portion using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to change url on click language name. Just append the current path after language portion. For example: change url https://example.com/de_DE/about-us/ to https://example.com/us_EN/about-us/ and vice versa.
I have tried this code but not proper working

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
$("#eng_btn").click(function()
{
     var bn_pathname = window.location.href;
     var en_pathname = bn_pathname.replace("/de_DE/","/en_Us/"); 
    window.location.href = en_pathname;

});

$("#ger_btn").click(function()
{
     var bn_pathname = window.location.href;
     var en_pathname = bn_pathname.replace("/en_Us/","/de_DE/"); 
     window.location.href = en_pathname;

});
</script>
```

```html
<div class="sidebar_lang">
 <span>Language:</span>
 <div class="lang_option">
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" id='ger_btn' class="lang_txt">DE</a>
 <a href="javascript:void(0)" id="eng_btn" class="lang_txt">EN</a>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your code is working fine but you need to include the jQuery library.

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Answer (score 0):

it is working fine for me

```js
var url = 'https://beta.yourtaxi.ch/de_DE/about-us/'

$("#eng_btn").click(function()
{
     var en_pathname = url.replace("/de_DE/","/en_Us/"); 
     console.log( en_pathname);

});

$("#ger_btn").click(function()
{
     var en_pathname = url.replace("/en_Us/","/de_DE/"); 
     console.log( en_pathname);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="sidebar_lang">
 <span>Language:</span>
 <div class="lang_option">
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" id='ger_btn' class="lang_txt">DE</a>
 <a href="javascript:void(0)" id="eng_btn" class="lang_txt">EN</a>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: console.log( en_pathname)?

Comment: the url is building fine, i do not see any problem in this code. what problem you are facing ?

Comment: I can't able to replace from both the languages

Comment: but i don't see any error in your code, check my snipet it is giving correct urls

Comment: Yes you are right. But I don't know why it is not working for me

Answer (score 0):

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="sidebar_lang">
    <span>Language:</span>
    <div class="lang_option">
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" id='ger_btn' class="lang_txt" target="_blank">DE</a>
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" id="eng_btn" class="lang_txt" target="_blank">EN</a>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#eng_btn").click(function()
{
     var bn_pathname = window.location.href;
     var en_pathname = bn_pathname.replace("/de_DE/","/en_Us/"); 
    window.location.href = en_pathname;

});

$("#ger_btn").click(function()
{
     var bn_pathname = window.location.href;
     var en_pathname = bn_pathname.replace("/en_Us/","/de_DE/"); 
     window.location.href = en_pathname;

});
});
</script>
```

Comment: When I click on en_Us it is showing this url https://beta.yourtaxi.ch/de_DE/en_Us